# read.socrata format all variables as characters

Tags: r, function, formatting, socrata

I am using read.socrata to download a private dataset using the following code

```
# Download private dataset
socrataEmail <- Sys.getenv("SOCRATA_EMAIL", "mark.silverberg+soda.demo@socrata.com")
socrataPassword <- Sys.getenv("SOCRATA_PASSWORD", "7vFDsGFDUG")
privateResourceToReadCsvUrl <- "https://soda.demo.socrata.com/resource/a9g2-feh2.csv" # dataset
read.socrata(url = privateResourceToReadCsvUrl, email = socrataEmail, password = socrataPassword, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to download all variables in the set in character format, but the current function has no option for this. Does anyone have advice for how I might achieve this? I know altering the function is an option, but anything easier?

Answer (score 0):

Right now, there isn't a way to specify that, but it has been [recommended](https://github.com/Chicago/RSocrata/issues/151) before. Happy to continue that consideration and discussion<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Always happy to accept pull requests!

Comment: I took a pass at finding a critical section of `read.socrata`code and tried modifying `getSodaTypes`, but failed to find the right nexus for coercing returned types to be character. I'm not at all familiar with the socrata data format, so this was a very amateurish effort on my part.

Answer (score 0):

How about a wrapper to coerce column classes class to character?

```
read.socrata.chr <- function( ... )
    data.frame(lapply( read.socrata(...), as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Very light testing:

str(read.socrata.chr(url = privateResourceToReadCsvUrl, email = socrataEmail, password = socrataPassword, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: chr  "24323" "4324" "2346"
 $ y: chr  "2432" "2342" "3465"
```